# Can I automatically resize text in pygame to fit screen resolution?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game to publish onto a website using python, and pygame.  I designed the program on my laptop, but when I tried running it on my Raspberry Pi, the text went off the border of the screen.  Is there any way to resize the text to fit the resolution of different displays?  `

```
screen.blit(gameOver, gameOverrect)
strScoreL = len(strScore)
scoreLabel = myfont.render("Your Score: " + strScore, 1, BLACK)
if strScoreL >= 2:
    screen.blit(scoreLabel, (80, 180))
else:
    screen.blit(scoreLabel, (60, 180))
```

`

Comment: `pygame.Font`s have a `size()` method which will tell you the amount of space needed to render text. You could use that to pick a size that's big enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the text depends on the [*Font*](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) object. If you want to render a text with a different size you need to create a *Font* with a different size.

e.g. create the *Font* depending on the with of the screen:

```py
font_size = screen.get_width() // 20
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, font_size)
```